# Multithreading attempt Python fail

Tags: windows, python-3.x, python-multithreading

The following code is an attempt of mine at a voice recognition program. The voice recognition works fine and can understand me, but I encountered a problem at certain points in the program  the code would sort of freeze, or hang but without an error.

To get around this I attempted to add a timer using multi-threading which should begin at `a = True` and after 3 seconds the program would automatically close. If the recognising worked perfectly the `a = False` should stop the timer before it closed the program. This obviously hasn't worked or I wouldn't be here.

I added a few print statements here and there so I could visually see where the code was when running, and I saw the the code for the timer begins however the code for voice recognition does not.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
import os, threading, time, sys
import subprocess as sp

print("Voice Recognition Software\n\n***********************************\n")

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def run():
        print("Checking")
        while True:
            if a == True:
                if a == False:
                    continue
                for x in range(3):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if a == False:
                        break
                sys.exit()  
def program():
    while True:
        print("voice recog has begun")
        r.energy_threshold = 8000
        t = None
        with sr.Microphone() as source:

            print (">")
            a = True
            audio = r.listen(source)
            a = False
            try:
                a = True
                print("Processing...")
                t = r.recognize_google(audio)
                a = False
                print (": " + t)
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Unknown input")
                continue
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("An error occured at GAPI\nA common cause is lack of internet connection")
                continue

            if "open" in t:
                t = t.replace("open","")
                t = t.replace(" ","")
                t = t + ".exe"
                print (t)

                for a,d,f in os.walk("C:\\"):
                    for files in f:
                         if files == t.lower() or files == t.capitalize() or files == t.upper():
                            pat = os.path.join(a,files)
                            print (pat)
                            sp.call([pat])
                            success = True
            if success == True:
                continue

a = False
success = False

thread1 = myThread.run()
thread2 = myThread.program()

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

EDIT:
I see some mistakes of my own here like indentation of the def function but even after fixing what I see it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: You don't have to implement your own timer class. It's already defined for you as `threading.Timer`. Have it call a function after a timeout that checks whether an event such as `success_event = threading.Event()` is set. The event should be passed as an argument to the function, e.g. `timer = threading.Timer(3, check_success, (success_event,));` `time.start()`. If it's not set, `check_success` can exit the process via `sys.exit` or abruptly via `os._exit`.

Comment: Pass the `success_event`  to `program` as well, and on success set it, i.e. `success_event.set()`.